# Scraping TikTok

Tags: python

Estoy realizando un código en python para realizar un scraping de TikTok. El código es el siguiente:

```
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi

api = TikTokApi()

for video in api.trending.videos():
    print(video.author.username) #Esto nos dará los nombres de los usuarios que son trending
    video_bytes = video.bytes()
    break
    
async for video in api.trending.videos():
    print(video.as_dict)
```

En la ejecución de este me da el siguiente error: 'async_generator' object is not iterable

No consigo conectarme con TikTok para poder extraer datos.

Answer (score 0):

`api.trending.videos()` retorna un [generador asíncrono](https://peps.python.org/pep-0525/), que debes consumir usando `await for`, que debe ejecutarse dentro de una corrutina.

No tengo experiencia con este paquete, pero algo así:

```
import asyncio
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi


async def trending_videos():
    async with TikTokApi() as api:
        await api.create_sessions()
        api = TikTokApi()

        async for video in api.trending.videos():
            print(video.author.username) #Esto nos dará los nombres de los usuarios que son trending
            video_bytes = video.bytes()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(trending_videos())
```